# Are $\sigma = (1234567)$ and $\tau = (1324567)$ conjugate in $A_7$?

Tags: group-theory

Are $\sigma = (1234567)$ and $\tau = (1324567)$ conjugate in $A_7$? Hint: how unique is an element $\rho$ in $S_7$ with $\rho \sigma \rho ^{-1} = \tau$?

---

So $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are conjugate in $S_7$ with $\rho \sigma \rho ^{-1} = \tau$ for some $\rho$. We can construct this $\rho$ as follows:

$\rho(1)=1$
$\rho(2)=3$
$\rho(3)=2$
$\rho(4)=4$
$\rho(5)=5$
$\rho(6)=6$
$\rho(7)=7$

This gives $\rho = (23)$ and since this is a transposition $(23) \notin A_7$. Now I would like to conclude that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are not conjugate in $A_7$ but I didn't use the hint and I didn't prove that $(23)$ is the only element that gives $\rho \sigma \rho ^{-1} = \tau$. Intuitively I believe this is the only element (since we have to send $2$ to $3$ and all the other numbers to themselves) but I can't really prove this. Also, I'm doubting whether this is the right approach. Could somebody help me out?

- How do I show that $\rho$ is unique?
- Is this the right approach?

Comment: Note that if $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are conjugate in $A_7$, then they are conjugate in $S_7$. Conjugacy classes in $S_n$ consist of permutations with the same cycle structure. What can you conclude from this?

Comment: Are you sure the first permutation isn't by any chance $\sigma = (1234567)$?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

The two permutations are $\sigma = (1234567)$ and $\tau = (1324567)$.

You have noted that $\sigma^{(23)} = \tau$. Now let $g$ be an arbitrary permutation such that $\sigma^{g} = \tau = \sigma^{(23)}$. Then $\sigma^{g \cdot (23)} = \sigma$ (as $(23)^{-1} = (23)$), that is, $g \cdot (23)$ centralizes $\sigma$.

Now there is a standard way to determine the centralizer of $\sigma$ in $S_{7}$. Since there are $6!$ cycles of length $7$ in $S_{7}$, and they are all conjugate to $\sigma$ in $S_{7}$, orbit-stabilizer tells you that the centralizer of $\sigma$ in $S_{7}$ has order $7! / 6! = 7$. Hence the centralizer is $\langle \sigma \rangle \le A_{7}$. Hence all $g \cdot (23)$ are even, and since $(23)$ is odd, so is $g$.

So there is no $g \in A_{7}$ such that $\sigma^{g} = \tau$.

---

BTW, this proves that $(23)$ is not unique. Exactly the seven elements $\sigma^{i} (23)$, for $0 \le i < 7$, conjugate $\sigma$ to $\tau$.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. It's pretty clear once you figure out you can make use of the centralizer of $\sigma$.